# Adding a new field to Category Bundle Orocommerce

Tags: symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

I'm trying to add a ManyToManyRelation to the category entity, but i get an error that the field doesnt exist when i clear cache.

```
 public function up(Schema $schema, QueryBag $queries)
    {
        $this->createNewGammeTable($schema);
        $this->extendExtension->addManyToManyRelation(
            $schema,
            self::CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME,
            "new_ranges",
            self::NEW_GAMME_TABLE_NAME,
            ["gamme_id"],
            ["gamme_id"],
            ["gamme_id"],
            [
                "extend" => ["owner" => ExtendScope::OWNER_CUSTOM, 'cascade' => ['all']],
                'form' => [
                    'form_type' => NewGammeCollectionType::class
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
    protected function createNewGammeTable(Schema $schema)
    {
        $table = $schema->createTable(self::NEW_GAMME_TABLE_NAME);
        $table->addColumn("id", "integer", ["autoincrement" => true]);
        $table->addColumn("gamme_id", "integer", ["notnull" => false]);
        $table->addColumn("sort_order", "integer");
        $table->setPrimaryKey(["id"]);
    }
```

So when i clear cache i get :

```
In RuntimeReflectionService.php line 76:
                                                                               
  Property Oro\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category::$new_ranges does not exi  
  st
```

and in dev env i dont get this error. but in the orocommerce plateforme when i try to edit a category i get

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.sort_order AS sort_order_2, t0.gamme_id AS gamme_id_3 FROM gdm_new_gamme t0 INNER JOIN oro_rel_ff3a7b9752519dfcec0789 ON t0.id = oro_rel_ff3a7b9752519dfcec0789.newgamme_id WHERE oro_rel_ff3a7b9752519dfcec0789.category_id = ?' with params [2]:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'oro_db.oro_rel_ff3a7b9752519dfcec0789' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Do you have a `new_ranges` property within your `CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME` table/class?

Comment: No i dont, $this->extendExtension->addManyToManyRelation() should add it no ?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by updating my entities using `oro:entity-extend:cache:clear`
and `oro:entity-extend:update-schema`